# How to find the next 4 days from the current day using javascript

Tags: javascript

I found the current day as Mar 27 2012 ....

```
var currentday = currentday.format("mmm d yyyy");
```

I want to find the add three days with this value.
i.e. i need the output as Mar 30 2012.

I also need to find the starting and ending date of a calendar. i.e. Feb 26 2012 - Mar 31 2012 to display the current month as displaying in calendar month view.

Can any one help me on this please....

Answer (score 1):

```
var currentday = new Date();
var nextDay = new Date();
nextDay.setDate(currentday.getDate() + 4);
```

Comment: alert(nextDay.setDate(currentday.getDate() + 4)); returns "1333191873209", how to convert it into Mar 31 2012 format. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: @saran for date formatting, have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript). There is no built in way to format a date if you need the day & month names.

Comment: @saran The quick and dirty for what you want is `var months = new Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", 
"Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", 
"Oct", "Nov", "Dec"); alert(months[nextDay.getMonth()] + " " + nextDay.getDate() + " " + nextDay.getFullYear());`

Answer (score 0):

```
//Set number of days you want to compute to
var days=4;

//Get current date or whatever date you want to compute from
var currentDate=new Date();

var nDaysFromNow=new Date();
nDaysFromNow.setDate(currentDate.getDate()+days);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add days using the getDate() function like so:

```
var someDate = new Date();
someDate = someDate.getDate() + 3;
```

Comment: i got the output as "1333191873209", how to convert it into Mar 31 2012 format. Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

See code below.. Hope it helps

```
var days = 4;
var next = new Date((new Date).getTime() +  ((1000*3600*24) *days));
```